# Eloquent query to list items visibility constraints

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm struggling with an Eloquent query. My end goal is to list all public posts authored by anyone and also the private ones that were authored by a given user from a given publication.

### Example:

#### Given these 3 posts

**title:** Title 1 | **user_id:** 1 | **is_private:** true

**title:** Title 2 | **user_id:** 2 | **is_private:** false

**title:** Title 3 | **user_id:** 3 | **is_private:** true

#### The output for userId 1 should be:

Title 1 and Title 2

My best shot at it was this the following:

```
    $posts =  Post::where('publication_id', $publicationId)
        ->where('is_private', false)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('owner_id', auth()->id())
                ->where('is_private', true);
        });
```

Which I know it's far from what is need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May work if second where statement is changed to `orWhere`

```
$posts = Post::where('publication_id', $publicationId)
    ->where('is_private', false)
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('owner_id', auth()->id)
            ->where('is_private', 'true');
    });
```

The reason being is the first where will restrict the second where to only search the public posts to check for private posts. This won't produce the desired result.

All the best.

Comment: I was kinda close then. It is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$posts =  Post::where('publication_id', $publicationId)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_private', false)
            ->orWhere('owner_id', auth()->id());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$posts =  Post::where('publication_id', $publicationId)
                       ->where('is_private', false)
                       ->orWhere('owner_id', auth()->id())
                       ->get();
```